# How to fill the picture with define color based on the cell type in R

Tags: r

I have the cell outline picture and the center coordinations of each cell,

[image]

I would like to fill the cell with different color based on the cell type in R, like this picture:

[image]

What package or function can be used for it? Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, '**image_fill**' function in the '**magick**' package can be used.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html